# DataGrid Autogenerates columns each time with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.net site in which I have a method called DisplayPersons which lists all the persons in the database. Thing is when I click on the ShowUsers button it calls the DisplayPersons function and binds data to the gridview and works fine. When I click the button for the second time it keeps duplicating the data to the the grid view by repeating the data. 
I want something like if the ShowUsers button is clicked it only needs to show data thats present in the database irrespective of how many times its clicked. Please help. Please ignore the other functions

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function SavePersonRecord() {

            var Name = $.trim($('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val());
            var LName = $.trim($('#<%=txtLastName.ClientID %>').val());

            var Messege = "";

            if (Name == '') {
                Messege = "FirstName is blank ";
            }

            if (LName == '') {
                Messege += "LastName is Blank";
            }

            if (Messege.length == 0) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/InsertPersonRecord",
                    data: "{'Name':'" + Name + "', 'LName':'" + LName + "'}",
                    success: function (Record) {

                        $('#txtName').val();
                        $('#txtLastName').val();


                        if (Record.d == true) {

                            $('#Result').text("Your Record has been inserted successfuly");
                            $('#txtName').val('');
                            $('#txtLastName').val('');
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#Result').text("Your Record was Not Inserted");
                        }

                    },
                    Error: function (textMsg) {

                        $('#Result').text("Error: " + Error);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#Result').html('');
                $('#Result').html(Messege);
            }
            $('#Result').fadeIn();
        }

        function DisplayPersons() {
            //document.write("a");
            $("#gvData").val('');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/BindUsers",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#gvData").append("<tr><td>" + result.d[i].FirstName + "</td><td>" + result.d[i].LastName);
                        result.d[i] = null;
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
        function SearchData()
        {
            var search = $.trim($('#<%=txtserach.ClientID %>').val());
            if (search == "") {
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/Search",
                data: "{'term':'" + search + "'}",
                success: function (found) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < found.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#gvData").append("<tr><td>" + found.d[i].FirstName + "</td><td>" + found.d[i].LastName);
                        found.d[i] = null;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    </script>

    <h3 id="Result"></h3>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>FirstName </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>Last Name</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnInsertRecord" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="SavePersonRecord(); return false" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><input type="button" value="Show Users" onclick="DisplayPersons()" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

            </asp:Table>
            <br /><br />

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtserach" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="SearchData()" />
             <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" ForeColor="#333333">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS File:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    static List<Users> allUsers;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindToGrid();
        }


    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool InsertPersonRecord(string Name, string LName)
    {
        bool InsertData;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_PersonData", con))
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", LName);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (Result > 0)
                {
                    InsertData = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    InsertData = false;
                }

                return InsertData;
            }
        }

    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Users> BindUsers()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        allUsers = new List<Users>();
        allUsers.Clear();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName from Users Order By FirstName", con))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Users users = new Users();
                        users.FirstName = dtrow["FirstName"].ToString();
                        users.LastName = dtrow["LastName"].ToString();
                        allUsers.Add(users);

                    }
                }



        }
        return allUsers;

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Users> Search(string term)
    {
        //List<Users> result = new List<Users>();
        return allUsers.FindAll(x => x.FirstName.Contains("term"));
    }

    public void BindToGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
        gvData.DataSource = dt;
        gvData.DataBind();
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the grid view using `html('')`, instead of `val('')`.

```
function DisplayPersons() {
    $("#gvData").html('');
    // Removed for brevity.
}
```

The method `val()` only works for form inputs, as stated in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

However, [`html()` works](http://api.jquery.com/html/) if you want to get/set the contents of any elements.

> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

Comment: Yea I tried html(' ') initially since it didnt work I tried val(' ')

Comment: Hey Jia it worked Fine. I dont know how but initially when I tried it didnt work. Thank you very much..